# Closing previous form box in C++ .net

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-c++-2005

I am using Visual C++ 2005 and I am creating an application that has various forms. What I am wanting to happen is when a new form is opened the previous one is closed. I'm sure it's just one line of code that I need to add but being new to this I have no idea what that is. The form I want to close is Form1.h. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Parts ^parts = gcnew Parts();
                 parts->ShowDialog();
                 this->Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by simply calling the Close() method from the form you wish to close. 
Have you tried that?

Comment: so surely this->Close(); should work because when the new form is opened the previous is still in the background.

Comment: I didn't quite understand if you meant that this solved your problem. It did?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the previous form is does not close when the new one is opened.

Comment: Can you post your code? The order of the instructions is relevant.

Comment: By doing that, the Close method will only be called once the ShowDialog returns, and that will only happen when you for instance close the new form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4876/discussion-between-seth-and-bigbaz34)

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the second form (Parts), you must use *Show* instead of *ShowDialog*. ShowDialog block the execution and the Close method won't be called until the form Parts is closed.

```
Parts ^parts = gcnew Parts();
parts->Show(); // Show the form and continue execution
this->Close();
```

But keep one thing in mind, if the caller form is the main window of application, when the method *Close* is called the whole application will be closed, and with it the form Parts will be closed too. To work around this behaviour, i would start the application with a invisible form. When that form is loaded, then your "caller" form will be started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is in C++ but in C# you can do it like this

```
static Programm
{
    static bool run = true;
    static int state = 1;
    /// <summary>
    /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        while (run)
        {
            Application.Run(getForm());
        }
    }

    static private Form getForm()
    {
        Form ret = null;

        switch (state)
        {
            case 1:
                ret = new Form1();
                break;
            case 2:
                ret = new Form2();
                break;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    static public void setState(int i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            run = false;
        }
        else
        {
            state = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps